# Using org-ref to download pdfs using sci-hub as a fallback

Tags: pdf, org-ref

I've developed a solution that allows to download pdfs from sci-hub as a fallback option to the functions provided by org-ref. I am a newbie to elisp, so please feel free to update this answer as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer** Use it at your own risk.

You have to add one new function and update another. Both can be declared in your init.el file as follows

1- The `sci-hub-pdf-url` function is

```lisp
;; Sci-hub
(defun sci-hub-pdf-url (doi)
  "Get url to the pdf from SCI-HUB"
  (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* (concat "https://sci-hub.se/" doi) ;captcha
        *doi-utils-waiting* t
        )
  ;; try to find PDF url (if it exists)
  (url-retrieve (concat "https://sci-hub.se/" doi)
            (lambda (status)
              (goto-char (point-min))
              (while (search-forward-regexp "\\(https://\\|//sci-hub.se/downloads\\).+download=true'" nil t)
                (let ((foundurl (match-string 0)))
                  (message foundurl)
                  (if (string-match "https:" foundurl)
                  (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* foundurl)
                (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* (concat "https:" foundurl))))
                (setq *doi-utils-waiting* nil))))
  (while *doi-utils-waiting* (sleep-for 0.1))
  *doi-utils-pdf-url*)
```

2- And update the `doi-utils-get-bibtex-entry-pdf` function by

```lisp
  (defun doi-utils-get-bibtex-entry-pdf (&optional arg)
    "Download pdf for entry at point if the pdf does not already exist locally.
The entry must have a doi. The pdf will be saved to
`org-ref-pdf-directory', by the name %s.pdf where %s is the
bibtex label.  Files will not be overwritten.  The pdf will be
checked to make sure it is a pdf, and not some html failure
page. You must have permission to access the pdf. We open the pdf
at the end if `doi-utils-open-pdf-after-download' is non-nil.

With one prefix ARG, directly get the pdf from a file (through
`read-file-name') instead of looking up a DOI. With a double
prefix ARG, directly get the pdf from an open buffer (through
`read-buffer-to-switch') instead. These two alternative methods
work even if the entry has no DOI, and the pdf file is not
checked."
    (interactive "P")
    (save-excursion
      (bibtex-beginning-of-entry)
      (let ( ;; get doi, removing http://dx.doi.org/ if it is there.
        (doi (replace-regexp-in-string
          "https?://\\(dx.\\)?.doi.org/" ""
          (bibtex-autokey-get-field "doi")))
        (key (cdr (assoc "=key=" (bibtex-parse-entry))))
        (pdf-url)
        (pdf-file))
    (setq pdf-file (concat
            (if org-ref-pdf-directory
                (file-name-as-directory org-ref-pdf-directory)
              (read-directory-name "PDF directory: " "."))
            key ".pdf"))
    ;; now get file if needed.
    (unless (file-exists-p pdf-file)
      (cond
       ((and (not arg)
         doi
         (if (doi-utils-get-pdf-url doi)
             (setq pdf-url (doi-utils-get-pdf-url doi))
           (setq pdf-url "https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/")))
        (url-copy-file pdf-url pdf-file)        
        ;; now check if we got a pdf
        (if (org-ref-pdf-p pdf-file)
        (message "%s saved" pdf-file)
          (delete-file pdf-file)
          ;; sci-hub fallback option
          (setq pdf-url (sci-hub-pdf-url doi))
          (url-copy-file pdf-url pdf-file)
          ;; now check if we got a pdf
          (if (org-ref-pdf-p pdf-file)
          (message "%s saved" pdf-file)
        (delete-file pdf-file)
        (message "No pdf was downloaded.") ; SH captcha
        (browse-url pdf-url))))
       ;; End of sci-hub fallback option
       ((equal arg '(4))
        (copy-file (expand-file-name (read-file-name "Pdf file: " nil nil t))
               pdf-file))
       ((equal arg '(16))
        (with-current-buffer (read-buffer-to-switch "Pdf buffer: ")
          (write-file pdf-file)))
       (t
        (message "We don't have a recipe for this journal.")))
      (when (and doi-utils-open-pdf-after-download (file-exists-p pdf-file))
        (org-open-file pdf-file))))))
```

3- Enjoy! If you have set up the `org-ref-pdf-directory` the command `crossref-add-bibtex-entry` or `doi-utils-add-bibtex-entry-from-doi` should download the pdf automatically to the specified directory. If not, it will open sci-hub in your browser (this usually happens when you have to enter a captcha). Good luck.