# Using org-ref to download pdfs or djvu using sci-hub and libgen as fallbacks

Tags: pdf, org-ref

As a continuation of [my previous post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58861/using-org-ref-to-download-pdfs-using-sci-hub-as-a-fallback/58862#58862), I've developed a solution that allows to download pdfs or djvu files from sci-hub or libgen as fallback options to the functions provided by org-ref. I am a newbie to elisp, so please feel free to update this answer as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** Use it at your own risk.

Notes: The current solution will download the first book in the first mirror listed in libgen, whether it is a pdf or djvu file, and add it to the `file` field of the bibtex entry. Because books are quite large it might take a while to get the file back (consider changing the `doi-utils-async-download` variable). If there is nothing to download whether on sci-hub or libgen the process will run indefinitely.

You have to add two new functions and update another. Both can be declared in your init.el file as follows

1- The `sci-hub-pdf-url` and `libgen-pdf-url` functions are

```lisp
;; Libgen
(defun libgen-pdf-url (isbn)
  "Get url to the pdf from libgen"
  (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* (concat "http://libgen.rs/search.php?req=" isbn) ; website url
        *doi-utils-waiting* t)
  ;; Mirror webpage: select first mirror from first entry
  (url-retrieve (concat "http://libgen.rs/search.php?req=" isbn)
                (lambda (status)
                  (goto-char (point-min))
                  (while (search-forward-regexp "\\('http://library.\\).*?'" nil t)
                    (let ((foundurl (replace-regexp-in-string "'" "" (match-string 0))))
                      (message "%s" foundurl)
                      (with-temp-buffer ;; Download webpage: find url from get button
                        (url-retrieve  foundurl
                                       (lambda (status2)
                                         (goto-char (point-min))
                                         (while (search-forward-regexp "\\(http://\\).+\">GET" nil t)
                                           (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* (replace-regexp-in-string "\">GET" "" (match-string 0)))
                                           (message "%s" *doi-utils-pdf-url*)                          
                                           (setq *doi-utils-waiting* nil)))))))))
  (while *doi-utils-waiting* (sleep-for 0.1))
  *doi-utils-pdf-url*)

;; Sci-hub
(defun sci-hub-pdf-url (doi)
  "Get url to the pdf from SCI-HUB"
  (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* (concat "https://sci-hub.se/" doi) ;captcha
        *doi-utils-waiting* t)
  ;; try to find PDF url (if it exists)
  (url-retrieve (concat "https://sci-hub.se/" doi)
                (lambda (status)
                  (goto-char (point-min))
                  (while (search-forward-regexp "\\(location.href=\\|'\\).+download=true'" nil t)
                    (let ((foundurl (match-string 0)))
                      (message "%s" foundurl)
                      (cond ((string-match "https:" foundurl) (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* foundurl))
                            ((string-match "/downloads" foundurl) (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* (concat "https://sci-hub.se" (replace-regexp-in-string "location.href='" "" foundurl))))
                            (t (setq *doi-utils-pdf-url* (concat "https:" (replace-regexp-in-string "location.href='" "" foundurl))))
                            )
                      )
                    (setq *doi-utils-waiting* nil))))
  (while *doi-utils-waiting* (sleep-for 0.1))
  *doi-utils-pdf-url*)
```

2- And update the `doi-utils-get-bibtex-entry-pdf` function to

```lisp
;; ** Finally, download the pdf
;; ###autoload
(defun doi-utils-get-bibtex-entry-pdf (&optional arg)
  "Download pdf for entry at point if the pdf does not already exist locally.
         The entry must have a doi. The pdf will be saved, by the name
         %s.pdf where %s is the bibtex label. Files will not be
         overwritten. The pdf will be checked to make sure it is a pdf,
         and not some html failure page. You must have permission to
         access the pdf. We open the pdf at the end if
         `doi-utils-open-pdf-after-download' is non-nil.

         With one prefix ARG, directly get the pdf from a file (through
         `read-file-name') instead of looking up a DOI. With a double
         prefix ARG, directly get the pdf from an open buffer (through
         `read-buffer-to-switch') instead. These two alternative methods
         work even if the entry has no DOI, and the pdf file is not
         checked."
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (bibtex-beginning-of-entry)
    (let (;; get doi, removing http://dx.doi.org/ if it is there.
          (doi (replace-regexp-in-string
                "https?://\\(dx.\\)?.doi.org/" ""
                (bibtex-autokey-get-field "doi")))
          (key (cdr (assoc "=key=" (bibtex-parse-entry))))
          (pdf-url)
          (pdf-file))

      (setq pdf-file
            (concat (cond
                     ((stringp bibtex-completion-library-path)
                      bibtex-completion-library-path)
                     ((= 1 (length bibtex-completion-library-path))
                      (car bibtex-completion-library-path))
                     (t
                      (completing-read "Dir: " bibtex-completion-library-path)))
                    key ".pdf"))
      (print (not arg))
      ;; now get file if needed.
      (unless (file-exists-p pdf-file)
        (cond
         ((and (not arg)
               doi
               (setq pdf-url (doi-utils-get-pdf-url doi))) ; problem
          (url-copy-file pdf-url pdf-file)
          ;; now check if we got a pdf
          (if (org-ref-pdf-p pdf-file)
              (message "%s saved" pdf-file)
            (delete-file pdf-file)
            ;; libgen/sci-hub fallback option
            (if (string= "" (bibtex-autokey-get-field "isbn"))
                (setq pdf-url (sci-hub-pdf-url doi))
              (setq pdf-url (libgen-pdf-url (bibtex-autokey-get-field "isbn"))))
            (message "%s" pdf-url)
            (url-copy-file pdf-url pdf-file)
            ;; now check if we got a pdf
            (if (org-ref-pdf-p pdf-file)
                (message "%s saved" pdf-file)
              (delete-file pdf-file)
              (message "No pdf was downloaded.")
              (browse-url pdf-url))))
         ((equal arg '(4))
          (rename-file (expand-file-name (read-file-name "Pdf file: " nil nil t))
                       pdf-file))
         ((equal arg '(16))
          (with-current-buffer (read-buffer-to-switch "Pdf buffer: ")
            (write-file pdf-file)))
         (t
          (message "We don't have a recipe for this journal.")
          (if (string= "" (bibtex-autokey-get-field "isbn")) ; book
          (progn (message "Attempting Sci-hub fall-back option.")       
                     (setq pdf-url (sci-hub-pdf-url doi)) ;article
                     (message "%s" pdf-url)
                     (url-copy-file pdf-url pdf-file)
                     ;; now check if we got a pdf
                     (if (org-ref-pdf-p pdf-file)
                         (message "%s saved" pdf-file)
               (delete-file pdf-file)
               (message "No pdf was downloaded.")
               (browse-url pdf-url)))
            (progn (message "Attempting libgen fall-back option.")      
                   (setq pdf-url (libgen-pdf-url (bibtex-autokey-get-field "isbn")))
                   (if (string-match "[.]djvu" pdf-url) ; check if it is a djvu file
                       (setq pdf-file (concat (file-name-sans-extension pdf-file) ".djvu")))
                   (url-copy-file pdf-url pdf-file)))))

        (when (file-exists-p pdf-file)
          (bibtex-set-field "file" pdf-file))

        (when (and doi-utils-open-pdf-after-download (file-exists-p pdf-file))
          (org-open-file pdf-file))))))
```

3- Enjoy! If you have set up the `org-ref-pdf-directory` the command `crossref-add-bibtex-entry`, `org-ref-clean-bibtex-entry` or `doi-utils-add-bibtex-entry-from-doi` should download the pdf/djvu file automatically to the specified directory. Good luck.